# Cyclic dependency amongst objects while serialization in java

Tags: java, serialization, cycle

While studying serialization in Java I came across this statement "while serialization the whole object graph of object is written to the stream" .So what if there is cycle in object graph ? What happens while deserialization  in this case and why ?

Comment: I found your requested  hope this helps http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151055/what-happens-if-we-serialize-and-deserialize-two-objects-which-references-to-eac

Comment: The Java serialization subsystem accounts for cycles.  And for multiple references to the same object.  And for other interesting things.  If the object is successfully serialized, then deserializing it yields an object whose graph is equivalent to the original's.  The details are too broad for this venue, however.

Comment: In fact, @MouseEvent, I am not wrong at all, as you seem to have discovered.  Here's [a simple demonstration](http://ideone.com/zo47zc) for anyone else who may be doubtful.  One can certainly treat the subject in much greater depth, but as I said, full details are too broad for SO.

Comment: omjego, did you try ot out yourself? Seems you should.

Comment: @MouseEvent It is you who is totally wrong. Otherwise please explain the purpose of `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` and `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()`. Your claim about 'bloated files' is ridiculous: a handle is smaller than the object it represents. Handling it manually does not improve on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Serialization handles cyclic object graphs via a 'handle' system. A previously serialized object is not re-serialized: instead, a 'handle ' to that object is serialized, which is reconstructed on deserialization to refer to the same object. See the [Object Serialization Specification #1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4176).

Comment: I was thinking about the same procedure. Like if the object is already written to stream then go back and find out where it is and give that reference  here .

Comment: That's not the same procedure. What you describe would create two objects.

Comment: How would  it creates more two objects ? What do you mean by "handle" ?There is only one copy serialized before and if it comes again for serialization we will find out if it is already written before on stream .If it is then serialize "handle" otherwise serialize the whole object.

Comment: @omjego I think it stores the objects similarly to how it stores them in memory (each object has an identifier and objects can hold references to other objects via identifiers).